# Blender normal map and reflections

Tags: texturing

Ive just downloaded blender 2.82 and opened my project im working on currently and noticed a big difference in the textures. Below are 2 pictures of before using 2.82 beta and the second using new 2.82 release.
Can anyone shed some light on what has happened.

Thanks,

Danny
[image: Blender 2.82 Beta]
[image: 2.82 full]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). This looks like Eevee has *Screenspace Reflections* and *Ambient Occlusion* disabled. Is that the case?

Comment: Hi and thanks for replying.
I should have said this is in cycles. Sorry.

Danny

Comment: Could you add screenshots of your scene setup? Perhaps check the world shading tab, maybe something changed in there.

Comment: Hopefully this is what your asking for.

Ive had to put the screenshots in first post as i cant figure out how to add it here.